# ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/var/task/package.json' - pdf2json

Tags: node.js, webpack-5, pdf2json

I'm trying to get the no of pages from pdf using pdf2json.its thowing below error.

I'm using the webpack 5 and nodejs18

```
{
    "errorType": "Error",
    "errorMessage": "ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/var/task/package.json'",
    "code": "ENOENT",
    "errno": -2,
    "syscall": "open",
    "path": "/var/task/package.json",
    "stack": [
        "Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/var/task/package.json'",
        "    at Object.openSync (node:fs:603:3)",
        "    at Object.readFileSync (node:fs:471:35)",
        "    at 61447 (/var/task/index.js:2:2588589)",
        "    at __webpack_require__ (/var/task/index.js:2:4081767)",
        "    at s (/var/task/index.js:2:2365892)",
        "    at new Promise (<anonymous>)",
        "    at /var/task/index.js:2:2365865",
        "    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)",
        "    at /var/task/index.js:2:2365505",
        "    at new Promise (<anonymous>)"
    ]
}
```

Need to calculate the page count for given pdf document. webpack 4 its working fine , after upgrade to nodejs18 and webpack 5 its not working,

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/lambda.ts',
  target: 'node',
  mode: 'production',
  externals: [{ 'aws-sdk': 'commonjs aws-sdk' }],
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(ts|tsx)?$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'ts-loader'
          }
        ],
        exclude: /node_modules/
      },
      {
        test: /\.m?js/,
        resolve: {
          fullySpecified: false
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.wasm', '.mjs', '.tsx', '.ts', '.js', 'jsx', '.json']    
  },
  output: {
    filename: 'index.js',
    hashFunction: 'xxhash64',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'webpacked'),
    libraryTarget: 'commonjs2'
  },
  stats: { timings: true },
  // plugins: [new webpack.IgnorePlugin(/^pg-native$/)],
  ignoreWarnings: [    
    { module: /sequelize/ },
    { module: /any-promise/ },
 
  ]
};
```